# What communication protocols can I use with maximum 2Mbps, with simple a simple cable (two wires, unshielded, untwisted)?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, bus, serial-bus, lan

I need to find a communication protocol/module (on market product) in order to provide M2M (max 64 devices) communication at a maximum rate of 2 Mbps and a range of up to 30 m.

The cables/cable should be just simple copper cable (unshielded and untwisted). Although CAN is a possible alternative, it is expensive.

After I made a search, I couldn´t find any good alternatives, therefore I would like to ask the community for possible ideas.

Comment: Why exactly is CAN "expensive"? It may for example enable unshielded cables where other technologies might not, and shielded cables are expensive for sure.

Comment: @Lundin the most possible primitive and cheap solution is required. I told CAN is expensive just as a reference to define expectation better.

Comment: "CAN is a possible alternative" - alternative to what?

Comment: @alfonso I really don't see how you could make a 64 node multi-drop bus cheaper by using some home-made solution. What's the price you are concerned about, if it isn't the cables? Some manner of driver/transceiver will always be required and they are quite cheap compared to what you get for the price. Internal ESD protection etc.

Comment: @Lundin that`s the question what is the cheapest option (if there is) and how, if not why? I agree with you but as said, just asked to get more opinions. It seems CAN is the only reasonable way

Comment: cheap, > 1 Mb/s: sounds like USB to me

Comment: What about Ethernet? Sure, you need twisted pair, but it’s a proven technology which will most definitely work both in terms of number of devices, distances, bit rate. It’s quite cheap, though of course “cheap” is relative. What’s your topology requirements? Where are the 30m?

Answer (score 2):

> Although CAN is a possible alternative, ...

CAN max bitrate is 1 Mbps.

> ... it is expensive.

Actually, it isn't. CAN is designed to be one of the cheapest short-distance, noise-proof communication protocols especially for in-vehicle or industrial environment communications.

RS-485 can be an option as 10 Mbps is possible up to 50 feet or 15 metres. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485), bitrate (in bps) times the distance (in meters) should not exceed 10<sup>8</sup>. In other words signalling at a rate of 2 Mbps is possible at up to 50 metres.

The number of nodes are limited to 32 in an RS-485 physical layer so you may consider CAN anyways.

Comment: CAN FD can get clocked faster in the data part of the message.

Comment: RS-485 transceivers exist that allow more than 32 devices, so it should not be ruled out.